# How to get number of sides of a polygon given side length?

Tags: geometry, polygons

If it's given that a polygon is equilateral and equiangular is it possible to determine the number of sides given the side length? Thanks for your help.

Comment: No. You can get an equilateral triangle and a square, both with side length 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not since e.g. an equilateral triangle can have any side length. You'd need more constraints.